# Xcode code folding issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-folding

After updating Xcode(5.0.1),one of my project files is automatically unfolding the code every time i leave the file or close Xcode.And this weird behavior is bothering me a lot,i already tried to delete and recreate it but didn't worked.

Anyone knows what might be causing this single file to have its code unfolded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around it. xCode will unfold your code automatically. Period. There is no option to "preserve" code folding. (sad, but true...)

Comment: The problem is that the code is being unfolded only in one file,like you sad there's no default option but since i use Xcode,when i save a file with the code folded,when i re-open it the code remains folded!

Comment: Yeah, It's bothering me a lot. Any solution..? @MateusNunes.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode-9, this issue is resolved. Code folding is being remembered and saved by Xcode 9 Editor.

Code you have/had folded exact before last source build/save, is automatically stored upon document/file closure. And same will be visible as it was (folded) when you will open document/file next time.

You don't need to do anything (there is no any option in Xcode tool bar to enable or disable) to save your code fold.